# How to connect different controls to different objects with data binding

Tags: wpf

I have two objects in the code behind of a Window.

```
namespace PL
{

public partial class Window6 : Window
{

    Currency Euro;
    Currency USD;
    public Window6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Euro = new Currency();
        USD = new Currency();


    }
}
}
```

This is how the Window's XAML will look like:

```
<Window x:Class="PL.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window6" Height="319.2" Width="680.8">
<Grid>
    <Label Name="Label1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Name="Label2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,46,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

I want that two different labels on the window will each be connected to one of the objects, the content field of Label1 will be connected to the "Currency Euro" object ,to it's "currentCurrency" field.Also Label2 will be connected to the USD object ,to it's "currentCurrency" field.

Since I can only define one datacontext to the grid, I can currently work with one object alone.

How can I connect both to different controls ? (I tried to find similar answers but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model class which contains the 2 values.
You then set that class as the data context which will enable you to do a binding.

In an ideal world, you would create a model and a view model.
The model is just the data and the model view is what you bind which also include notify property changed and any other business logic.

Comment: How the binding syntax will look like ?, since there are two different objects I can't refer only to the field itself like this :                     Content="{Binding currentCurrency}"

Comment: You model would contain the 2 currency objects. Your view model would then have the 2 string properties you want to display, these are coded in the c#. In the window class bind the Data context to a new instance of your view model. The on the label, using a standars wpf data binding to the property names in your view model.  Here is more information on MvvM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: Thanks, say I have them ready the model called Model, and the viewModel called ViewModel and it contains this two objects.How the syntax of the specific binding for the field "currentCurrency" of the object "Currency Euro" would look like ?

Comment: In your view model you would need to map the EUR and USD currentCurrency to 2 properties in your view model.  You would then be able to do content="{Binding eurCurrenyCurrency}”